# How to enforce pyspark reader to use specified schema instead of inferring one from parquet?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a parquet file which has some schema. It involves some invalid characters, so I want to use my own schema. Let's say the parquet metadata contains `original_schema` and I have `new_schema` which is obtained by renaming most of the fields of `original_schema`, so they both have same length and order. I do

```py
df = spark.read.schema(new_schema).parquet(source)
```

However, if column present in both schemas, it will be fine, but if it is present only in `new_schema`, it will be `null`. As if instead of using `new_schema` reader just try to find columns from it in the `original_schema`. Changing option `mergeSchema` doesn't change anything.

Full code:

```py
df1 = spark.read.parquet(source)
schema = df1.schema
new_fields = [
    StructField(f.name.replace('.', '___').replace('(', '-').replace(')', '-'), f.dataType, f.nullable) for f in schema.fields
]
new_schema = StructType(new_fields)

df2 = spark.read.schema(new_schema).parquet(source)
```

How can I force reader to use `new_schema` for parquet file?

Comment: you could just rename the columns after reading the data. `sdf.withColumnRenamed('oldname', 'newname')`

Comment: @samkart, I have to solve the invalid characters problem, renaming doesn't work

Comment: but you're essentially renaming the fields in your code

Comment: @samkart, Yes, but I try to do it on stage of reading via new schema. If you read dataframe with the old one, it seems to be impossible to rename it due to invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

A read DataFrame can be converted to an RDD[Row], and new Dataframe can be created with new schema. Scala example:

```
val df = Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)).toDF("a", "b")


val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField(name = "c", dataType = IntegerType),
    StructField(name = "d", dataType = IntegerType)
  )
)

val result = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+
|c  |d  |
+---+---+
|1  |2  |
|3  |4  |
+---+---+
```